# Creating a new bitmap with given dimensions filled with given color

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I'm creating a program using the Win32 API, and I need to create a new bitmap filled with one color and with given dimensions.

Here is my code:

```
m_hBitmap =( HBITMAP ) CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, iWidth, iHeight);

HDC hDCn = CreateCompatibleDC( hDC );
SelectObject( hDCn, m_hBitmap );

ExtFloodFill(hDCn, 0, 0, crColor, FLOODFILLSURFACE);

DeleteDC( hDCn );
```

The bitmap dimensions match, but the bitmap is always black regardless of the `crColor` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`FillRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect) instead of `ExtFloodFill()`.

Also, you need to de-select the bitmap before you delete the DC, otherwise the original bitmap created and selected into the DC by `CreateCompatibleDC()` will be leaked.

Try this:

```
m_hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, iWidth, iHeight);

HDC hDCn = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
HBITMAP hOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hDCn, m_hBitmap); // <-- SAVE OLD BITMAP! 

//ExtFloodFill(hDCn, 0, 0, crColor, FLOODFILLSURFACE);
RECT r;
r.left = r.top = 0;
r.right = iWidth;
r.bottom = iHeight;
HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(crColor);
FillRect(hDCn, &r, hBrush);
DeleteObject(hBrush);

SelectObject(hDCn, hOld); // <-- RESTORE OLD BITMAP
DeleteDC(hDCn);
```

Comment: The bitmap after display is still black

Comment: In addition, the usage of [`ExtFloodFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-extfloodfill) is wrong. `ExtFloodFill` uses the brush color currently selected in `hDCn`. `crColor` relates to existing color drawn in `hDCn`. `ExtFloodFill` expects to find an area with `crColor` found at that coordinate `{0,0}` - the asker probably wants `FillRect`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks. I added it to my answer.